# Trouble finding path in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path, grid

I am trying to find number of paths between top left and bottom right cells on a checker board. i can only move to the adjacent right and adjacent bottom cell. This way i can have a maximum of 2 non intersecting simple paths. I am using a recursive approach.

```
    private void processMatrix() 
{
    if(matrix[0][0]!=1 || matrix[0][0]!=matrix[ROWS-1][COLUMNS-1])
        System.out.println("No Path Exists between bottom right and top left cells");
    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    traverse(row,col);
}

    private boolean traverse(int row, int col) 
{
    path.add(new Point(row,col));

    if(row+1<ROWS)
    {
        if(matrix[row+1][col]==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(matrix[row+1][col]==1)
        {
            traverse(row+1,col);
        }
    }
    if(col+1<COLUMNS)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col+1]==0)
         {
             return false;
         }
        if(matrix[row][col+1]==1)
        {
            traverse(row,col+1);
        }
    }
    if(col==COLUMNS-1 && row==ROWS-1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But with this code i am only able to traverse the lower triangular matrix. And when i reverse the order of if blocks in the traverse() function i am only able to traverse a path in the upper triangular matrix. Unable to figure out what is wrong. I also want to detect intersecting paths. Please help.

**EDIT:**
The matrix consists of 0s and 1s.
A path exists if it is connected by adjacent cells containing only 1s. In other words the path will be a chain of 1s.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overcomplicating things with your code. If your matrix is 0s and 1s, use boolean instead of int. Non-intersecting paths seems a bit silly, since all paths are equally valid in taxicab geometry. Here's the simple solution for finding the number all paths, it will show you how it works with the block of system.out prints:

```
int rows = 9;
int columns = 8;
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[rows][columns];
for (boolean[] arr : matrix) {/* Set values of matrix such that true = can pass thru that space, false = space blocked */
    Arrays.fill(arr, true);
}
matrix[4][6] = false;
matrix[2][5] = false;
int[][] paths = new int[rows][columns];//number of paths reaching each space in i steps
paths[0][0] = 1; //Starting space
for (int i = 0; i < rows + columns - 2; i++) {//Taxicab distance is always x+y, i = distance travelled so far
    int[][] newPaths = new int[rows][columns]; //number of paths reaching each space in i+1 steps
    for (int x = i >= columns ? i - columns + 1 : 0; x <= i && x < rows;) { //x is traditionally columns but it doesn't matter
        int y = i - x; //if statement is x declaration ensures that this is < columns
        int newX = x + 1; //will be used repeatedly
        int newY = y + 1; //will be used repeatedly
        if (newX < rows && matrix[newX][y]) newPaths[newX][y] += paths[x][y];
        if (newY < columns && matrix[x][newY]) newPaths[x][newY] += paths[x][y];
        x = newX;
    }
    paths = newPaths;
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) { //optional, show the algorithm at work
        for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
            int r = paths[x][y];
            System.out.print(r);
            if (r < 100) System.out.print(" ");
            if (r < 10) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(paths[rows - 1][columns - 1]); //result
```

If all you want to determine is whether a path exists, replace int[][] paths with boolean[][] paths and change the operations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental dynamic programming problem.

Let `dp[R][C]` be the number of paths from the top-left cell to the cell on row `R` and column `C` (1-indexed).

1. Initial values (when R or C is 1):

   - `dp[R][1] = 1` if `matrix[i][1]` has value 1 for `i = 1..R`, otherwise `dp[R][1] = 0`.
   - `dp[1][C] = 1` if `matrix[1][j]` has value 1 for `j = 1..C`, otherwise `dp[1][C] = 0`.
2. Then `dp[R][C]` = `dp[R-1][C]` + `dp[R][C-1]` if `matrix[R][C] = 1`, otherwise `dp[R][C] = 0` (for R, C >= 2)

And this is it. The intuition behind this idea is that if we know that we can get to cell on row R-1, column C by N different roads, then if we go down once, we will get N different roads to cell [R, C]. Analogically for going right from cell [R, C-1] to [R, C].

Finally, the answer is in `dp[N][M]`, where N and M are the dimensions of the matrix.